# LB/ UB period of decimal

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the lower bound/ upper bound of the period of  $\frac{1}{p}$ where $p$ is prime?

All I could think of was that if finite, the next number of a decimal is 0. Then I came up with examples for trivial cases and couldn't get far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period $n$ of the decimal expansion of $1/p$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $p$ divides $10^n - 1$.

Since $9$ always divides $10^n - 1$, we must have $$p \leq \frac{10^n -1}{9}.$$

Therefore, we have a **lower bound** for the period $n$,
$$n \geq \log_{10}(9p+1).$$
Since there are examples of $n = \log_{10}(9p+1)$, e.g. prime $p=1111111111111111111$, this bound is "sharp".

On the other hand, by [*Fermat's little theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), we have that $p$ always divides $10^{p-1} - 1$.  Thus we have an **upper bound** for the period $n$,
$$n \leq p-1.$$

Again, it is not possible to improve this upper bound, because there are examples of primes $p$ such that $p$ does *not* divide $10^m -1$ for any $m$ less than $p-1$.  For example, the primes $7$, $17$, $19$ and $23$ have this property.  In fact, such primes, called [*cyclic primes*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicNumber.html), appear to be fairly common, occuring about $32\%$ of the time when checked empirically.

However, it is only conjectured, and not yet proven, that there are infinitely many cyclic primes.  More precisely, it is conjectured that the proportion of primes that are cyclic is given by [*Artin's constant*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArtinsConstant.html), $C_{\text{Artin}} = 0.3739558136\dots$.

ADDED LATER (at Akash's request)

Suppose $1/p$ is given by the repeating decimal $0.\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_n}$.  Then,
$$\frac{1}{p} = 0.\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_n} = 10^{-1}a_1 + 10^{-2}a_2 + \cdots 10^{-n}a_n + 10^{-n-1}a_1 + \cdots = (10^{-n}+10^{-2n}+\cdots)(10^{n-1}a_1 + 10^{n-2}a_2 + \cdots + a_n) = \frac{10^{n-1}a_1 + 10^{n-2}a_2 + \cdots + a_n}{10^n-1}.$$
Thus
$$p(10^{n-1}a_1 + 10^{n-2}a_2 + \cdots + a_n) = 10^n-1,$$
so $p$ divides $10^n-1$.  Conversely, if $p$ divides $10^n-1$, you can show that $1/p$ has a decimal expansion that repeats after $n$ places.

Therefore, the fundamental period of the repeating decimal of $1/p$ is equal to the smallest $n$ such that $p$ divides $10^n-1$.

Comment: Nice solution, but can you give me an explanation of why  'The period $n$ of the decimal expansion of $1/p$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $p$ divides $10^n - 1$.'? Everything else is good.

Comment: Hi Akash.  You can find part of the explanation above now.

Comment: I fully undertand it now - thank you very much for the explanation.